# Create an ASCII art table from tabular data

Tags: command-line, text-processing, columns, csv

Given perhaps comma- or tab-delimited input, I'd like to present a series of appropriately padded columns to stdout, so I can easily scan columnar information which would otherwise present rather messily.

I've tried `troff`-based solutions and while the simple demos have worked, feeding the command actual input has resulted in bizarre errors. I've currently resorted to using a `sed`-based <strike>method</strike> hack which is rather slow...

**EDIT**: `column` is quite a useful tool, ***however*** it'd be really awesome if I the columns had, say, a pipe character (`|`) between them so they do not appear to "float" in space and I can easily distinguish where each starts.

*PS. This post's title used to read 'ASCII "table"', not 'ASCII-art table'. Edited to try and remove confusion.*

Answer (score 18):

Assuming a CSV file, you can use `column(1)` like so:

```
column -ts, your_file
```

This is included in the `bsdmainutils` package on my Debian distribution, so I'm not sure how portable it is.

Two more things to note:

1. The above example is simplistic; explore the man page for more details on how to format your output.
2. It does not fare well with quoted fields containing commas. I.e., it would consider `a,b,"c,d"` as four columns not three.

Comment: Combining it with `head` is useful: `column -ts, your_file | head`

Comment: "column -tns, file" works better when the head line has a blank cell left-side.

Answer (score 8):

If the tabular data is read in python somehow (in this example reading csv file with the Pandas module), the "tabulate" module is quite useful and simple.

```
import pandas
from tabulate import tabulate

data = pandas.read_csv('/tmp/foo.csv', index_col=0)
print(tabulate(data, headers=data.columns, tablefmt="grid"))
```

Which gives a nice output:

```
+-----+------+------+
|     |    A |    B |
+=====+======+======+
| foo | 1    |  0.2 |
+-----+------+------+
| bar | 3.14 | 10.9 |
+-----+------+------+
```

You can produce different styles

```
print(tabulate(data, headers=data.columns, tablefmt="fancy_grid"))

╒═════╤══════╤══════╕
│     │    A │    B │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ foo │ 1    │  0.2 │
├─────┼──────┼──────┤
│ bar │ 3.14 │ 10.9 │
╘═════╧══════╧══════╛
```

Comment: You can run the suggested code inside ipython (run `ipython` in your shell to start it)

Answer (score 7):

This will columnate the input file, adding a `|` character to surround each column.

```
 sed -e 's/^/| /' -e 's/,/,| /g' -e 's/$/,|/' inputfile | column -t -s,
```

Sample run (using a readily-available colon-delimited file):

```
$ head -4 /etc/passwd | tr : , | \
  sed -e 's/^/| /' -e 's/,/,| /g' -e 's/$/,|/' | column -t -s,

| root    | x  | 0  | 0  | root    | /root      | /bin/bash  |
| daemon  | x  | 1  | 1  | daemon  | /usr/sbin  | /bin/sh    |
| bin     | x  | 2  | 2  | bin     | /bin       | /bin/sh    |
| sys     | x  | 3  | 3  | sys     | /dev       | /bin/sh    |
```

Answer (score 4):

With `mlr` ([Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), `miller` package in Debian-based systems):

```
mlr --icsv --opprint --barred cat < file.csv
```

See the `mlr` man page for how to specify the input format (`--itsv` for instance for tab separated input).

Example:

```
$ cat file.csv
foo,bar
x,1.2
y,1.3
$ mlr --icsv --opprint --barred cat < file.csv
+-----+-----+
| foo | bar |
+-----+-----+
| x   | 1.2 |
| y   | 1.3 |
+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ideas above with a bit more to automatically add separator lines.

No Header Row

```
function csv_table () {
    table=$(echo "$1"|sed -e 's/^/,/' -e 's/$/,/' -e 's/,/,| /g' |column -t -s,);
    line=$(echo "$table" |head -n1 | sed -e 's/[^|]/-/g' -e 's/.$//' -e 's/|/+/g');
    echo ${line};
    echo "$table";
    echo ${line}
}
```

With Header Row

```
function csv_table_header () {
    table=$(echo "$1"|sed -e 's/^/,/' -e  's/$/,/' -e 's/,/,| /g' |column -t -s,)
    line=$(echo "$table" |head -n1 | sed -e 's/[^|]/-/g' -e 's/.$//' -e 's/|/+/g')
    echo ${line}
    echo "$table" | head -n1
    echo ${line}
    echo "${table}" | tail -n +2
    echo ${line}
}
```

Sample Data

```
some_csv_data='Column 1,Column 2,Column 3
1,2,3
apple,banana,cherry'
```

Output (no header)

```
$ csv_table "${some_csv_data}"
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Column 1  | Column 2  | Column 3  |
| 1         | 2         | 3         |
| apple     | banana    | cherry    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Output (with header)

```
$ csv_table_header "${some_csv_data}"
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Column 1  | Column 2  | Column 3  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | 2         | 3         |
| apple     | banana    | cherry    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: (1) We prefer answers with more explanation. (2) You should say `echo "$line"` rather than `echo ${line}`.  Or, if you *really* need to (and you can explain *why* you need to), `echo "${line}"`. (Or, really preferably, ```printf '%s\n' "$line"```.) (3) Your answer will choke a little if the header row (the first row of the input) contains any `|` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
raku -MTerminal::Table -e 'my @a = lines.map: *.split(",").list;  print-table(@a);'
```

OR

```
raku -MText::Table::Simple -e 'my @a = lines.map: *.split(",").list;  .say for lol2table(@a[0], @a[1..*]);'
```

Sample Input:

```
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3
1,2,3
apple,banana,cherry
```

Sample Output (using the `Terminal::Table` module):

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|
+--------+--------+--------+
|1       |2       |3       |
+--------+--------+--------+
|apple   |banana  |cherry  |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Sample Output (using the `Text::Table::Simple` module):

```
O----------O----------O----------O
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
O==========O==========O==========O
| 1        | 2        | 3        |
| apple    | banana   | cherry   |
----------------------------------
```

Above, `lines` are individually `split` on commas, converted to `list` format, and sent to module functions for printing.

Note: it's probably best to use a dedicated CSV parser for anything other that a 'simple-CSV' file (no commas-inside-quotations, no embedded newlines, etc.). Below is an example using Raku's `Text::CSV` module. Observe how fields are properly quoted in the output, and commas-within-doublequotes remain untouched:

```perl
~$ cat ./date_durian.csv
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4
1,2,3,4
apple,banana,cherry,"date, durian"
```

```perl
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @a = csv(in => $*IN, sep => ",") andthen csv(in => $_, out => $*OUT);'  < ./date_durian.csv
"Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4"
1,2,3,4
apple,banana,cherry,"date, durian"
```

```perl
~$ raku -MText::CSV -MText::Table::Simple -e 'my @a = csv(in => $*IN); .say for lol2table(@a[0], @a[1..*]);' < ./date_durian.csv
O----------O----------O----------O--------------O
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4     |
O==========O==========O==========O==============O
| 1        | 2        | 3        | 4            |
| apple    | banana   | cherry   | date, durian |
-------------------------------------------------
```

https://modules.raku.org/search/?q=CSV
https://modules.raku.org/t/TABLE
https://raku.org/